# How to implement CMAA

Tags: antialiasing

First, here's the link to the actual article that describes CMAA and how to do it.
https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/conservative-morphological-anti-aliasing-cmaa-update

My problem is that I can barely understand the steps involved. Either the wording is bad or my reading comprehension is bad, English not being my native language.

Could someone put it in simpler terms (Or maybe pseudocode if it's easier for you) so I can understand and implement it?

Specifically the steps 1 through 4.

Comment: So you're asking us to re-write the paper, except clearer? (This is  kind of a huge question.)

Answer (score 1):

Article is written very well, you are simply nowhere near to understand math and process involved, keep learning... also given the fact the there is link for source code in the article it makes me think you simply didnt even read it properly.

Link: https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/53/c8/CMAA1.3_26March2014.7z

Comment: Also if you are doing this, again, for XNA 4.0, just dont, you need bit operation in shader to make this really effective and by now you should now that you can´t do that in SM 3_0 (And XNA doesnt support newer)